# Silverstripe Twitter like url structure

Tags: silverstripe

I am trying to get a twitter like url structure using silverstripe, where the accounts have an own url on the root of the url, like:

http://twitter.com/MyAccountName

But there are also other routes that should be available, like http://twitter.com/search, that don't map on a user.

It's fairly easy to do something like this on a controller, but then you get something like this: http://twitter.com/account/MyAccountName

Is there a workable way to achieve this on the root of the site?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define routes for this. First step is to define all routes which are 'special' like search etc. Second step is to catch all remaining requests and forward them to the controller which handles your member profile pages. For example:

```
---
Name: customroutes
After: framework/routes#coreroutes
---
Director:
    rules:
        'search' : 'SearchController'    
        '$Action' : 'MemberProfilesController'
```

If you are using the MemberProfiles module.

Untested

Comment: The problem with this of course is that there are a lot of default routes in the system. Login an admin for example, or pages that are defined in the site tree. Do these keep functioning?

Comment: You can set this in the yml. e.g. 'After: cms/modelascontrollerroutes'. You just have to make sure your profile names don't conflict with cms's $URLSegment

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-linkmapping` module. It will setup redirects so a url such as `http://twitter.com/MyAccountName` will redirect to `http://twitter.com/account/MyAccountName`

Its not a perfect solution, but it will work.

I have used it on a website so the url `http://designersplace.com.au/heather-levi-interiors` will redirect to `http://designersplace.com.au/designers/profile/heather-levi-interiors`

I set up an hourly task to create / delete these link mappings. You could modify this to work for you.

```
<?php
class ProfileLinkMappingHourlyTask extends HourlyTask {



    function process(){

        //create link mapping records.
        $profiles = DataList::create('Profile')->filter(array('IsPublished' => true));
        foreach ($profiles as $p) {

            //check if mapping record exists.
            if (DataList::create('LinkMapping')->filter(array('MappedLink' => $p->URLSegment))->count() == 0) {
                $linkMapping = new LinkMapping();
                $linkMapping->MappedLink = $p->URLSegment;
                $linkMapping->RedirectType = 'Link';
                $linkMapping->RedirectLink = sprintf('designers/profile/%s', $p->URLSegment);
                $linkMapping->write();

                Debug::dump('Create link mapping: ' . $p->URLSegment);
            }
        }

        //delete un-used link mappings.
        $linkMappings = DataList::create('LinkMapping');
        foreach ($linkMappings as $lm) {
            if (DataList::create('Profile')->filter(array('URLSegment' => $lm->MappedLink))->count() == 0) {
                $query = sprintf('DELETE FROM LinkMapping WHERE ID=%d', Convert::raw2sql($lm->ID));
                DB::query($query);

                Debug::dump('Deleted link mapping: ' . $lm->URLSegment);
            }
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: Thanks for you idea. I now use a similar solution, and I want to get rid of the redirect. The customer (and I) don't like it. It has some seo and performance issues. A few weeks ago the system had to handle 90,000 requests in a few minutes. Needles to say, we are now looking into some improvements :-)

Comment: Maybe you can use the linkmappings module as a base to work from and instead of redirecting when a url is found, you could render a page.